# PHP date_default_timezone_set makes no change to the time() - why?

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

Why when I use `date_default_timezone_set()` does it make no difference to the `time()` ?

Surely I would expect the values of `$server_time` and `$local_time`, below, to be different?

```
$server_time = time();
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Guam');
$local_time = time();
print_r(get_defined_vars());

-------
/* echoed output */
Array
(
    [server_time] => 1314261374
    [local_time] => 1314261374
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timestamp is always without any timezone information. If you use date you see the difference:

```
$server_time=date(DATE_W3C);
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Guam');
$local_time=date(DATE_W3C);
print_r(get_defined_vars());

----
/* echoed output */
Array
(
    [server_time] => 2011-08-25T10:49:26+02:00
    [local_time] => 2011-08-25T18:49:26+10:00
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`time()` is timezone independant.

Answer (score 1):

`time()` returns the current Unix timestamp. If it depends the timezone, the programmers will be get crazy.